# mongoose.connect() url argument must be of type string

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, axios

I'm getting the following error when using mongoose.connect()

`error: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received undefined {"data":{"code":"ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE"}}`

I'm using it like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const url = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
mongoose.connect(url, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
});
```

I've also tried it without the environment variable:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://username:password@myurl.com/etc", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
});
```

The stack trace looks like this:

```
43|api-dev | TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
43|api-dev |     at validateString (internal/validators.js:124:11)
43|api-dev |     at Url.parse (url.js:160:3)
43|api-dev |     at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:155:13)
43|api-dev |     at dispatchHttpRequest (/var/www/api-dev/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:91:22)
43|api-dev |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
43|api-dev |     at httpAdapter (/var/www/api-dev/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:46:10)
43|api-dev |     at dispatchRequest (/var/www/api-dev/node_modules/axios/lib/core/dispatchRequest.js:52:10)
43|api-dev |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

It seems to be an axios error, but I'm not calling axios directly.

It works fine in my local environment, both with the env variable and the raw string, but not on my server. Ideas?

*The url string in this example has been replaced. I'm using the correct string in production.

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of `process.env.MONGODB_URL` in your web server? What's the output?

Comment: Yep, I've logged it, and it shows the correct value in the console. Not 'undefined'. But the issue doesn't seem to be `process.env.MONGODB_URL` because I'm still getting the error when I pass the raw url string to the `url` parameter of `mongoose.connect()`. I think my issue has to do with an axios call being made by mongoose somewhere.

Comment: Did you use the latest version of `mongoose`? Your way works fine for me in the latest version of `mongoose`.

Comment: I'm on mongoose 5.11.18. I think this error is coming from somewhere other than `mongoose.connect`, but I haven't found it yet. It seems to be an axios error. I'm not using axios explicitly, but I think mongoose does under the hood?

Comment: I see. Have you tried to add quotes to the raw MongoDB URI like in the second example? Like 'mongodb+srv://your-mongodb-string'. I noticed that you did not add the quotes in your connection string. It should work. If it works, I'm going to answer this question with that.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that in my application. That was a typo in my example. It's fixed now, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Nice! Then, please accept my answer. Thank you :)

Comment: I would if it worked! But I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you forgot to add double quotations in your Mongoose connection string.

The answer should be:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://username:password@myurl.com/etc", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
});
```

With the double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my missing double quotes; it's now fixed in my post. I have actually tried this but I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out not to be about `mongo.connect()` at all, but was a typo in an env variable for another part of my program.